# Stability factor in BJT

Tags: arduino, pcb, current, amplifier, gain

I was wondering if the stability factor is a feature for all BJTs and does one need two resistors in a voltage divider emitter bias or a single resistor is enough?

[image]

Comment: You don't *need* two resistors but you might *want* two resistors for a robust design.  It all depends on the specs and system requirements that you're trying to meet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Two stiff resistors (10 times lower impedance than base) will both establish a proper DC operating point (bias) and make the circuit way less sensitive to variation in the transistors (temperature, part to part, load variance). You never want to design a linear transistor circuit based on its typical Beta (current gain) factor. This is wildly variable. However, if you are operating the transistor in saturation and cutoff (digitally, like a switch) one transistor is acceptable because at these operating points, behavior is not sensitive to base current (and temperature) variations.

Comment: Okay  thanks alot

Comment: ....."one transistor is acceptable".... I suppose you mean "one resistor", right?

Answer (score 0):

Yes - it can be (and has been) shown that for amplifying purposes the best DC bias scheme is based on (a) a low-resistive voltage divider at the base node and (b) an emitter resistor providing negative DC feedback.

The DC current through the voltage divider should be as large as possible (in comparison to the DC current into the base) - however, with consideration of the allowable power consumption and the minimum acceptable signal input resistance.

It is the goal to make the DC voltage at the base node as "stiff" as possible (independent on the base current which is subject of very large tolerances and uncertainties). When there is sufficient negative DC feedback it is not very important if the design then is based on Vbe=0.65 or Vbe=0.7 volts. In any case and for each amplifier stage, negative feedback makes the DC operating point insensitive to variations/uncertainties of the parameters of the active device.